# Is there a way to make Opera a different proxy than what is set by the system?

Tags: opera

One of the major reasons why I uninstalled Opera recently is that they removed the proxy configuration so now Opera uses the default system settings.

I wonder is there, however, some way to specify a different proxy settings for Opera?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Append  `--proxy-server="ip:port"` to your Opera shortcut like:

```
"C:\Programs\Opera\launcher.exe" --proxy-server="62.103.107.9:80"
```

Some Google Chrome switches work in Opera too since they use the same underlying technologie.

#### Further links

- [Syntax for proxy switch](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/5245/google-chrome-how-to-assign-a-proxy-server-that-is-different-from-internet-explorers-settings/). Make sure to include the quotes and the port
- [Full list of Chromium switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: Tested with Opera 28. Make sure no other extensions like [Zenmate](https://addons.opera.com/de/extensions/details/zenmate-for-operatm/?display=en) take exclusive control over your proxy setting

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! :) I did not know about this option to the Opera executable.

Comment: doesnt work in Opera version 73.0.3856.284

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can set proxies without passing by system configuration would be to use an extension dedicated to that purpose.

The simplest solution in my opinion would be to keep an earlier version of Opera, and use it when needed.

Comment: I was hoping there is some undocumented "feature". - Typically some less-known configuration parameter or something similar.